# Prove that $\chi(X \times Y)=\chi(X)\,\chi(Y) $ for finite CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite CW Complexes. Prove that
$$\chi(X \times Y) = \chi(X) \, \chi(Y),$$ where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristics.

I have thought in this way that if $X= e_{1}^{0}\cup e_{1}^{0}...\cup e_{k}^{0}\cup e_{k+1}^{1}....\cup e_{l}^{1}....\cup e_{m}^{n}$ and $Y= e_{1}^{0}\cup e_{1}^{0}...\cup e_{k_1}^{0}\cup e_{{k_1}+1}^{1}....\cup e_{l_1}^{1}....\cup e_{m_1}^{n}$. Then $X \times Y$ is the products of corresponding $r$ cells. So am I right? And please give me the right answer in details.

Again anyone think it w.r.t homology groups?

Comment: Indeed, every cell of the product is a product of cells of the factors, so you just have to carefully count everything.

Comment: Will you please explain counting...

Comment: In order to compute the Euler characteristic of a CW complex you have to know how many $k$-cells it has for each $k$. Well: how many $k$-cells does $X\times Y$ has?

Comment: Yes I know. Because  it is sum oh $c_n$ where $c_n$ is the no of $n$ cells in $X$. Now for an easy case suppose $X$ has $n_1$ $0$ cells & $n_2$ $1$ cells and $Y$ has $n_3$ $0$ cells only. Now can you explain $X  \times Y$ has how many which cells?

Comment: Do you know what is the CW structure on the product? What re its cells?

Comment: No this is what I can't see. But my intuition tells me that product over each individual cells will happen.. Will you please give me the answer?

Comment: I suggest you look in a textbook what is the CW structure on the product.

Comment: In hatcher where do I get it?

Comment: Yes I have read it but couldn't understand how many $n$ cells are there in the product for each $n$? Will you tells me?

Comment: It is explicitly stated in page 8 of hatcher's book. In particular, read the subsection "products" under the section "Operations on spaces".

Comment: I have faced problems in seeing $e_{\alpha}^m \times e_{\beta}^n$. It is of what dimension, $m+n$?

Comment: Yes. An $n$-cell is (homeomorphic to) an open $n$-disk. So what is the product of a $m$-disk and an $n$-disk? If you have any more questions regarding this, I suggest you read the whole section on CW complexes from pages 5-8 in Hatcher first. You seem to have a very shaky grasp of what they actually are.

Comment: The Euler characteristic is denoted $\chi$, not $\Omega$, which is typically reserved for loop spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$\chi (X) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i  a_i $ where $ a_i $ is the number of i-cells that X has and n is the dimension of X.

Similarly let $ \chi(Y) = \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j b_j $.

Now $ \chi (X \times Y ) = \sum_{k=0}^{m+n} (-1)^k c_k $

For any index k, k-cells are created by r-cells and k-r cells from X and Y respectively where $ 0 \le r \le k $ (whenever such r and k-r cells exists in X and Y respectively).

Hence the number of k cells = $ \sum _{r=o}^k a_r b_{k-r} $

But $ (-1)^k \sum _{r=0}^k a_r b_{k-r} = \sum _{r=0}^k (-1)^r a_r (-1)^{k-r} b_{k-r} $

$\chi(X) \times \chi (Y) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i  a_i \right) \times \left ( \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j b_j  \right ) = \sum_{k=0}^{m+n} (-1)^k\sum _{r=0}^k a_r b_{k-r}  = \chi (X \times Y )$.